# Integration tests with webrat and Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrat, shoulda

I'm upgrading a Rails 2.3.5 app to Rails 3.0.3. But my integration tests
aren't working. I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass
```

The line to blame is

```
assert_select "input#artist.title.unsolved", 1
```

My test_helper.rb for webrat looks likes this:

```
require "webrat"
require 'webrat/core/matchers'
include Webrat::Methods

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :rack
end
```

I'm using shoulda 2.11.3 and webrat 0.7.3 for the testing. I've read,
that webrat and shoulda are compatible with Rails3.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Thanks!
tux

**ADDITION**:

It seems, that the NoMethodError appears from shoulda, not from Webrat, as mentioned in the title. Here is the trace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/selector.rb:605:in `response_from_page_or_rjs'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/selector.rb:213:in `assert_select'
    test/integration/user_integration_test.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <class:UserIntegrationTest>'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/shoulda-context-1.0.0.beta1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:412:in `call'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/shoulda-context-1.0.0.beta1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:412:in `block in run_current_setup_blocks'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/shoulda-context-1.0.0.beta1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:411:in `each'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/shoulda-context-1.0.0.beta1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:411:in `run_current_setup_blocks'
    /Users/23tux/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/shoulda-context-1.0.0.beta1/lib/shoulda/context/context.rb:393:in `block in create_test_from_should_hash'
```

And here is the whole block context around the assert_select:

```
class SongIntegrationTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  context "a visitor" do
    context "solving a song" do
      setup do
        @song = Song.make
        visit song_path(@song)
      end

      should "have two guess fields" do
        assert_select "input#artist.title.unsolved", 1
        assert_select "input#title.title.unsolved", 1
      end
```

Maybe the assert_select isn't longer available in Rails 3 with Shoulda.
Hope someone can help me!
thx!

Comment: I found out, that maybe the error comes from webrat, overriding the assert_select method:
https://webrat.lighthouseapp.com/projects/10503/tickets/395-assert_select-not-working-with-rails-300-due-to-webrat

But the fix shown at the link above, doesn't work (and btw, I'm not using cucumber).

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fork of webrat that works with rails3 at https://github.com/joakimk/webrat. At some point it should get pulled into the main branch. rails 2.3 is still very popular at this time.

Comment: Thx for your answer! But I decided to use capybara instead of webrat. It works fine with Rails3, and the tests are not so hard to rewrite for capybara